# GEKKO and Scipy.optimize lead to different results in nonlinear parameter estimation

Tags: python, gekko

I am learning how to use GEKKO for parameter estimation problems and
as a first step, I am developing example problems that I have
previously implemented using Scipy minimization routines. These have
been done following the information available in APMonitor.com and the
courses available within. The current problem is a batch reactor
simulation of a methanol-to-hydrocarbons process obtained from:
http://www.daetools.com/docs/tutorials-all.html#tutorial-che-opt-5

The model description can be followed in the code described  further
below, but the elementary steps considered are:

```
   A --> B   
   A + B --> C   
   C + B --> P   
   A --> C   
   A --> P   
   A + B --> P
```

where experimental data is available for concentrations of A, C, and P
as a function of time. The goal of the model is to estimate the rate
constants for the six elementary reactions (k1-k6). The difficulty I
am encountering right now is that my GEKKO model and my Scipy.optimize - based models lead to different parameter estimates, despite using the same experimental data and initial guesses for the parameters. I
have also compared this model to one developed using gPROMS and Athena
Visual Studio, with the scipy model agreeing with the parameter
estimates obtained with these closed-sourced programs. The estimated
parameters for each program are shown below:

- Scipy model (L-BFGS-B optimizer): [k1 k2 k3 k4 k5 k6] = [2.779, 0., 0.197, 3.042, 2.148, 0.541]
- GEKKO model (IPOPT optimizer): [k1 k2 k3 k4 k5 k6] = [3.7766387559, 1.1826920269e-07, 0.21242442412, 4.130394645, 2.4232122905, 3.3140978171]

Interestingly, both models lead to the same objective function value
of 0.0123 at the end of the optimization and look similar in the plots
of species concentration vs time. I have tried changing GEKKO's
optimizer and tightened tolerances to 1E-8 to no avail. My guess is
that my GEKKO model isn't properly set up, but I cannot find the issue
with it. Any help would be appreciated in pointing me to possible
issues that may be leading to the model discrepancies. I attach the
two scripts below:

#### Scipy model

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp
from scipy.optimize import minimize
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Experimental data
times  = np.array([0.0, 0.071875, 0.143750, 0.215625, 0.287500, 0.359375, 0.431250,
                      0.503125, 0.575000, 0.646875, 0.718750, 0.790625, 0.862500,
                      0.934375, 1.006250, 1.078125, 1.150000])
A_obs = np.array([1.0, 0.552208, 0.300598, 0.196879, 0.101175, 0.065684, 0.045096,
                      0.028880, 0.018433, 0.011509, 0.006215, 0.004278, 0.002698,
                      0.001944, 0.001116, 0.000732, 0.000426])
C_obs = np.array([0.0, 0.187768, 0.262406, 0.350412, 0.325110, 0.367181, 0.348264,
                      0.325085, 0.355673, 0.361805, 0.363117, 0.327266, 0.330211,
                      0.385798, 0.358132, 0.380497, 0.383051])
P_obs = np.array([0.0, 0.117684, 0.175074, 0.236679, 0.234442, 0.270303, 0.272637,
                      0.274075, 0.278981, 0.297151, 0.297797, 0.298722, 0.326645,
                      0.303198, 0.277822, 0.284194, 0.301471])

def rxn(x, k): #rate equations in power law form r = k [A][B]
    A = x[0]
    B = x[1]
    C = x[2]
    P = x[3]
    
    k1 = k[0]
    k2 = k[1]
    k3 = k[2]
    k4 = k[3]
    k5 = k[4]
    k6 = k[5]
    
    r1 = k1 * A
    r2 = k2 * A * B
    r3 = k3 * C * B
    r4 = k4 * A
    r5 = k5 * A
    r6 = k6 * A * B
    
    return [r1, r2, r3, r4, r5, r6] #returns reaction rate of each equation

#mass balance diff eqs, function calls rxn function 

def mass_balances(t, x, *args): 
        k = args
        r = rxn(x, k)
        dAdt = - r[0] - r[1] - r[3] - r[4] - r[5]
        dBdt = + r[0] - r[1] - r[2] - r[5]
        dCdt = + r[1] - r[2] + r[3]
        dPdt = + r[2] + r[4] + r[5]

        return [dAdt, dBdt, dCdt, dPdt]
    
IC = [1.0, 0, 0, 0] #Initial conditions of species A, B, C, P
ki= [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]

#Objective function definition

def obj_fun(k):   
#solve initial value problem over time span of data
    sol  = solve_ivp(mass_balances,[min(times),max(times)],IC, args = (k), t_eval=(times)) 
    y_model = np.vstack((sol.y[0],sol.y[2],sol.y[3])).T
    obs = np.vstack((A_obs, C_obs, P_obs)).T
    err = np.sum((y_model-obs)**2)
   
    return err

bnds = ((0, None), (0, None),(0, None),(0, None),(0, None),(0, None))
model = minimize(obj_fun,ki, bounds=bnds, method = 'L-BFGS-B')
k_opt = model.x

print(k_opt.round(decimals = 3))

y_calc = solve_ivp(mass_balances,[min(times),max(times)],IC, args = (model.x), t_eval=(times)) 

plt.plot(y_calc.t, y_calc.y.T)
plt.plot(times,A_obs,'bo')
plt.plot(times,C_obs,'gx')
plt.plot(times,P_obs,'rs')
```

#### GEKKO Model

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from gekko import GEKKO

#Experimental data
times  = np.array([0.0, 0.071875, 0.143750, 0.215625, 0.287500, 0.359375, 0.431250,
                      0.503125, 0.575000, 0.646875, 0.718750, 0.790625, 0.862500,
                      0.934375, 1.006250, 1.078125, 1.150000])
A_obs = np.array([1.0, 0.552208, 0.300598, 0.196879, 0.101175, 0.065684, 0.045096,
                      0.028880, 0.018433, 0.011509, 0.006215, 0.004278, 0.002698,
                      0.001944, 0.001116, 0.000732, 0.000426])
C_obs = np.array([0.0, 0.187768, 0.262406, 0.350412, 0.325110, 0.367181, 0.348264,
                      0.325085, 0.355673, 0.361805, 0.363117, 0.327266, 0.330211,
                      0.385798, 0.358132, 0.380497, 0.383051])
P_obs = np.array([0.0, 0.117684, 0.175074, 0.236679, 0.234442, 0.270303, 0.272637,
                      0.274075, 0.278981, 0.297151, 0.297797, 0.298722, 0.326645,
                      0.303198, 0.277822, 0.284194, 0.301471])


m = GEKKO(remote = False)

t = m.time = times


Am = m.CV(value=A_obs, lb = 0)
Cm = m.CV(value=C_obs, lb = 0)
Pm = m.CV(value=P_obs, lb = 0)

A = m.Var(1, lb = 0)
B = m.Var(0, lb = 0)
C = m.Var(0, lb = 0)
P = m.Var(0, lb = 0)

Am.FSTATUS = 1
Cm.FSTATUS = 1
Pm.FSTATUS = 1
    
k1 = m.FV(1, lb = 0)
k2 = m.FV(1, lb = 0)
k3 = m.FV(1, lb = 0)
k4 = m.FV(1, lb = 0)
k5 = m.FV(1, lb = 0)
k6 = m.FV(1, lb = 0)

k1.STATUS = 1
k2.STATUS = 1
k3.STATUS = 1
k4.STATUS = 1
k5.STATUS = 1
k6.STATUS = 1

r1 = m.Var(0, lb = 0)
r2 = m.Var(0, lb = 0)
r3 = m.Var(0, lb = 0)
r4 = m.Var(0, lb = 0)
r5 = m.Var(0, lb = 0)
r6 = m.Var(0, lb = 0)
   
m.Equation(r1 == k1 * A)
m.Equation(r2 == k2 * A * B)
m.Equation(r3 == k3 * C * B)
m.Equation(r4 == k4 * A)
m.Equation(r5 == k5 * A)
m.Equation(r6 == k6 * A * B)
    

#mass balance diff eqs, function calls rxn function 
m.Equation(A.dt() == - r1 - r2 - r4 - r5 - r6)
m.Equation(B.dt() ==  r1 - r2 - r3 - r6)
m.Equation(C.dt() ==  r2 - r3 + r4)
m.Equation(P.dt() ==  r3 + r5 + r6)

m.Obj((A-Am)**2+(P-Pm)**2+(C-Cm)**2)


m.options.IMODE = 5
m.options.SOLVER = 3 #IPOPT optimizer
m.options.RTOL = 1E-8
m.options.OTOL = 1E-8
m.solve()

k_opt = [k1.value[0],k2.value[0], k3.value[0], k4.value[0], k5.value[0], k6.value[0]]
print(k_opt)
plt.plot(t,A)
plt.plot(t,C)
plt.plot(t,P)
plt.plot(t,B)
plt.plot(times,A_obs,'bo')
plt.plot(times,C_obs,'gx')
plt.plot(times,P_obs,'rs')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are a couple suggestions:

- Set `m.options.NODES=3` or higher up to 6 to get better integration accuracy.
- Set `Am`, `Cm`, `Pm` as parameters instead of variables. They are fixed inputs.
- Try different initial conditions. There may be multiple local minima.
- The objective function may be flat so that different parameter values give the same objective function value. You can [test the parameter confidence intervals](https://apmonitor.com/che263/index.php/Main/PythonRegressionStatistics) to see if the data gives narrow or wide joint confidence regions.

Here are the results with the modifications:

[image: parameter estimation]

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from gekko import GEKKO

#Experimental data
times  = np.array([0.0, 0.071875, 0.143750, 0.215625, 0.287500, 0.359375, 0.431250,
                      0.503125, 0.575000, 0.646875, 0.718750, 0.790625, 0.862500,
                      0.934375, 1.006250, 1.078125, 1.150000])
A_obs = np.array([1.0, 0.552208, 0.300598, 0.196879, 0.101175, 0.065684, 0.045096,
                      0.028880, 0.018433, 0.011509, 0.006215, 0.004278, 0.002698,
                      0.001944, 0.001116, 0.000732, 0.000426])
C_obs = np.array([0.0, 0.187768, 0.262406, 0.350412, 0.325110, 0.367181, 0.348264,
                      0.325085, 0.355673, 0.361805, 0.363117, 0.327266, 0.330211,
                      0.385798, 0.358132, 0.380497, 0.383051])
P_obs = np.array([0.0, 0.117684, 0.175074, 0.236679, 0.234442, 0.270303, 0.272637,
                      0.274075, 0.278981, 0.297151, 0.297797, 0.298722, 0.326645,
                      0.303198, 0.277822, 0.284194, 0.301471])

m = GEKKO(remote=False)

t = m.time = times

Am = m.Param(value=A_obs, lb = 0)
Cm = m.Param(value=C_obs, lb = 0)
Pm = m.Param(value=P_obs, lb = 0)

A = m.Var(1, lb = 0)
B = m.Var(0, lb = 0)
C = m.Var(0, lb = 0)
P = m.Var(0, lb = 0)

k = m.Array(m.FV,6,value=1,lb=0)  
for ki in k:
    ki.STATUS = 1
k1,k2,k3,k4,k5,k6 = k

r1 = m.Var(0, lb = 0)
r2 = m.Var(0, lb = 0)
r3 = m.Var(0, lb = 0)
r4 = m.Var(0, lb = 0)
r5 = m.Var(0, lb = 0)
r6 = m.Var(0, lb = 0)
   
m.Equation(r1 == k1 * A)
m.Equation(r2 == k2 * A * B)
m.Equation(r3 == k3 * C * B)
m.Equation(r4 == k4 * A)
m.Equation(r5 == k5 * A)
m.Equation(r6 == k6 * A * B)

#mass balance diff eqs, function calls rxn function 
m.Equation(A.dt() == - r1 - r2 - r4 - r5 - r6)
m.Equation(B.dt() ==  r1 - r2 - r3 - r6)
m.Equation(C.dt() ==  r2 - r3 + r4)
m.Equation(P.dt() ==  r3 + r5 + r6)

m.Minimize((A-Am)**2)
m.Minimize((P-Pm)**2)
m.Minimize((C-Cm)**2)

m.options.IMODE = 5
m.options.SOLVER = 3 #IPOPT optimizer
m.options.RTOL = 1E-8
m.options.OTOL = 1E-8
m.options.NODES = 5
m.solve()

k_opt = []
for ki in k:
    k_opt.append(ki.value[0])
print(k_opt)

plt.plot(t,A)
plt.plot(t,C)
plt.plot(t,P)
plt.plot(t,B)
plt.plot(times,A_obs,'bo')
plt.plot(times,C_obs,'gx')
plt.plot(times,P_obs,'rs')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Hi John, thank you for your feedback. I took a look at your suggestions and the main modification that led to agreement between GEKKO and Scipy was the initial guess of the parameters. In particular, k2 which was essentially 0 led to the biggest changes in optimized results. Guesses of k2 = 0.1-0.2 and all other ki's = 1 led to the agreement. A guess of 1 led to a big discrepancy.  I find it curious, however, that the GEKKO solver had this sensitivity while the scipy optimize solver did not. Could this sensitivity be due to differences in modeling approach by GEKKO and scipy? Thank you again!

Comment: Gekko uses different solvers that can be set with `m.options.SOLVER`. You may want to try `m.options.SOLVER=1` or `m.options.SOLVER=2` to see if they get a better solution. All of the solvers in Gekko are local minimizers (as is Scipy.minimize) so they are all finding nearby local solutions that satisfy the KKT conditions: https://apmonitor.com/me575/index.php/Main/KuhnTucker when they report a successful solution.