# Using array variables in system of ODEs with GEKKO in python

Tags: python, gekko

I have previously posted questions regarding the use of GEKKO in the area of parameter estimation. The question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63350026/gekko-and-scipy-optimize-lead-to-different-results-in-nonlinear-parameter-estima) was very useful in understanding some of the workings of GEKKO, but one aspect I did not leverage was the use of array variables. In revisiting this problem, I realized my 'measured' data was wrong, because I included the initial (and unmeasured) conditions as part of my measured variables as the first element of the arrays. (I apologize as I am not sure how to make the python syntax highlighting happen)

```py
        #Experimental data
    times  = np.array([0.0, 0.071875, 0.143750, 0.215625, 0.287500, 0.359375, 0.431250,
                          0.503125, 0.575000, 0.646875, 0.718750, 0.790625, 0.862500,
                          0.934375, 1.006250, 1.078125, 1.150000])
    A_obs = np.array([1.0, 0.552208, 0.300598, 0.196879, 0.101175, 0.065684, 0.045096,
                          0.028880, 0.018433, 0.011509, 0.006215, 0.004278, 0.002698,
                          0.001944, 0.001116, 0.000732, 0.000426])
    C_obs = np.array([0.0, 0.187768, 0.262406, 0.350412, 0.325110, 0.367181, 0.348264,
                          0.325085, 0.355673, 0.361805, 0.363117, 0.327266, 0.330211,
                          0.385798, 0.358132, 0.380497, 0.383051])
    P_obs = np.array([0.0, 0.117684, 0.175074, 0.236679, 0.234442, 0.270303, 0.272637,
                          0.274075, 0.278981, 0.297151, 0.297797, 0.298722, 0.326645,
                          0.303198, 0.277822, 0.284194, 0.301471])
```

In revisitng this aspect, I ran into a problem where I had to specify to GEKKO an integration period, which had to include time = 0. This change in the time span for the simulation vs the measured data leads to issues with my objective functions not working due to different lengths of the terms:

```py
    m.Minimize((A-Am)**2) #Array A has 17 elements, array Am has 16
    m.Minimize((P-Pm)**2)
    m.Minimize((C-Cm)**2)
```

To try to get around this, I think I need to implement my variables with m.Array() so I can index them by element in the hopes of setting up objective functions of the form:

```py
    m.Obj(np.sum([(A[i+1]-Am[i])**2 for i in range(len(Am))]))
```

The complete code is shown at the end of the post, but my issue seems to be in setting up the m.Equations() of my system. Currently, I do not use indexes to refer to the individual elements of the variables:

```py
m.Equation(r1 == k1 * A )
m.Equation(r2 == k2 * A * B )
m.Equation(r3 == k3 * C * B )
m.Equation(r4 == k4 * A )
m.Equation(r5 == k5 * A )
m.Equation(r6 == k6 * A * B )

#mass balance diff eqs, function calls rxn function 
m.Equation(A.dt() == - r1 - r2 - r4 - r5 - r6 )
m.Equation(B.dt() ==  r1 - r2 - r3 - r6 )
m.Equation(C.dt() ==  r2 - r3 + r4)
m.Equation(P.dt() ==  r3 + r5 + r6)
```

The program give an error when using equations of this form:

```py
    m.Equation(A.dt() == - r1 - r2 - r4 - r5 - r6 )

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'dt'
```

When I try to set them up as an array, python freezes, as I think I must be generating too many equations or some other memory issue. Perhaps it is trying to differentiate each equation in the index individually, which is also not correct:

```py
m.Equation([r1[k] == k1 * A[k] for k in range(len(r1))])
m.Equation([r2[k] == k2 * A[k] * B[k] for k in range(len(r2))])
m.Equation([r3[k] == k3 * C[k] * B[k] for k in range(len(r3))])
m.Equation([r4[k] == k4 * A[k] for k in range(len(r4))])
m.Equation([r5[k] == k5 * A[k] for k in range(len(r5))])
m.Equation([r6[k] == k6 * A[k] * B[k] for k in range(len(r6))])

#mass balance diff eqs, function calls rxn function 
m.Equation([A[j].dt() == - r1[j] - r2[j] - r4[j] - r5[j] - r6[j] for j in range(len(A))] )
m.Equation([B[j].dt() ==  r1[j] - r2[j] - r3[j] - r6[j] for j in range(len(B))] )
m.Equation([C[j].dt() ==  r2[j] - r3[j] + r4[j] for j in range(len(C))])
m.Equation([P[j].dt() ==  r3[j] + r5[j] + r6[j] for j in range(len(P)) ])
```

If anybody could explain how to use array variables within equations, particulalry ODEs, it would be greatly appreciated, as I could not find any examples where array variables are part of a system of ODEs (I must have missed it in the many examples). Additionally, If there is another, perhaps simpler way, to write my objective functions with variables of different lengths (and not have to specify them as array variables as I had originally), that would be good to know as well.

Full script below:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from gekko import GEKKO

data = {'times':[0.071875, 0.143750, 0.215625, 0.287500, 0.359375, 0.431250,
                 0.503125, 0.575000, 0.646875, 0.718750, 0.790625, 0.862500,
                 0.934375, 1.006250, 1.078125, 1.150000],
        'A_obs':[0.552208, 0.300598, 0.196879, 0.101175, 0.065684, 0.045096,
                 0.028880, 0.018433, 0.011509, 0.006215, 0.004278, 0.002698,
                 0.001944, 0.001116, 0.000732, 0.000426],
        'C_obs':[0.187768, 0.262406, 0.350412, 0.325110, 0.367181, 0.348264,
                 0.325085, 0.355673, 0.361805, 0.363117, 0.327266, 0.330211,
                 0.385798, 0.358132, 0.380497, 0.383051],
        'P_obs':[0.117684, 0.175074, 0.236679, 0.234442, 0.270303, 0.272637,
                 0.274075, 0.278981, 0.297151, 0.297797, 0.298722, 0.326645,
                 0.303198, 0.277822, 0.284194, 0.301471]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.set_index('times',inplace = True)



m = GEKKO(remote=False)

time_obs = df.index

t = m.time = np.append(0,time_obs) #adding a time = 0 start value to time discretization for integration

Am= m.Array(m.Param,(len(time_obs)))
Cm= m.Array(m.Param,(len(time_obs)))
Pm= m.Array(m.Param,(len(time_obs)))

for i in range(len(time_obs)):
    
    Am[i].value = df.iloc[i]['A_obs']
    Cm[i].value = df.iloc[i]['C_obs']
    Pm[i].value = df.iloc[i]['P_obs']

A = m.Array(m.Var,(len(t)),lb=0,value=0.0)
A[0].value=1.0
B = m.Array(m.Var,(len(t)),lb=0,value=0.0)
C = m.Array(m.Var,(len(t)),lb=0,value=0.0)
P = m.Array(m.Var,(len(t)),lb=0,value=0.0)

k = m.Array(m.FV,6,value=1,lb=0)  
for ki in k:
    ki.STATUS = 1
k1,k2,k3,k4,k5,k6 = k


r1 = m.Array(m.Var,(len(t)),lb=0,value=0.0)
r2 = m.Array(m.Var,(len(t)),lb=0,value=0.0)
r3 = m.Array(m.Var,(len(t)),lb=0,value=0.0)
r4 = m.Array(m.Var,(len(t)),lb=0,value=0.0)
r5 = m.Array(m.Var,(len(t)),lb=0,value=0.0)
r6 = m.Array(m.Var,(len(t)),lb=0,value=0.0)
   
m.Equation(r1 == k1 * A )
m.Equation(r2 == k2 * A * B )
m.Equation(r3 == k3 * C * B )
m.Equation(r4 == k4 * A )
m.Equation(r5 == k5 * A )
m.Equation(r6 == k6 * A * B )

#mass balance diff eqs, function calls rxn function 
m.Equation(A.dt() == - r1 - r2 - r4 - r5 - r6 )
m.Equation(B.dt() ==  r1 - r2 - r3 - r6 )
m.Equation(C.dt() ==  r2 - r3 + r4)
m.Equation(P.dt() ==  r3 + r5 + r6)
'''
m.Equation([r1[k] == k1 * A[k] for k in range(len(r1))])
m.Equation([r2[k] == k2 * A[k] * B[k] for k in range(len(r2))])
m.Equation([r3[k] == k3 * C[k] * B[k] for k in range(len(r3))])
m.Equation([r4[k] == k4 * A[k] for k in range(len(r4))])
m.Equation([r5[k] == k5 * A[k] for k in range(len(r5))])
m.Equation([r6[k] == k6 * A[k] * B[k] for k in range(len(r6))])

#mass balance diff eqs, function calls rxn function 
m.Equation([A[j].dt() == - r1[j] - r2[j] - r4[j] - r5[j] - r6[j] for j in range(len(A))] )
m.Equation([B[j].dt() ==  r1[j] - r2[j] - r3[j] - r6[j] for j in range(len(B))] )
m.Equation([C[j].dt() ==  r2[j] - r3[j] + r4[j] for j in range(len(C))])
m.Equation([P[j].dt() ==  r3[j] + r5[j] + r6[j] for j in range(len(P)) ])
'''
m.Obj(np.sum([(A[i+1]-Am[i])**2 for i in range(len(Am))]))
m.Obj(np.sum([(C[i+1]-Cm[i])**2 for i in range(len(Cm))]))
m.Obj(np.sum([(P[i+1]-Pm[i])**2 for i in range(len(Pm))]))

m.options.IMODE = 5
m.options.SOLVER = 3 #IPOPT optimizer
m.options.RTOL = 1E-6
m.options.OTOL = 1E-6
m.options.NODES = 6
m.options.DIAGLEVEL = 10
#m.open_folder()
m.solve()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is no problem to use an Array variable, but this would require a customized implementation of the [collocation equations](https://apmonitor.com/do/index.php/Main/OrthogonalCollocation) to relate derivatives to the variables. It is much easier to put in a placeholder for the missing measurement and create a new parameter `mobj` to ignore certain measurements such as the initial measurement.

```py
# ignore first measurement
tobj = np.ones(len(t))
tobj[0] = 0
mobj = m.Param(tobj)
```

Arrays are useful to condense the code such as with the definition of variables.

```py
A,B,C,P = m.Array(m.Var,4,lb=0,fixed_initial=False)
```

Here is the solution:

[image: Solution]

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from gekko import GEKKO

data = {'times':[0,0.071875, 0.143750, 0.215625, 0.287500, 0.359375, 0.431250,
                 0.503125, 0.575000, 0.646875, 0.718750, 0.790625, 0.862500,
                 0.934375, 1.006250, 1.078125, 1.150000],
        'A_obs':[0,0.552208, 0.300598, 0.196879, 0.101175, 0.065684, 0.045096,
                 0.028880, 0.018433, 0.011509, 0.006215, 0.004278, 0.002698,
                 0.001944, 0.001116, 0.000732, 0.000426],
        'C_obs':[0,0.187768, 0.262406, 0.350412, 0.325110, 0.367181, 0.348264,
                 0.325085, 0.355673, 0.361805, 0.363117, 0.327266, 0.330211,
                 0.385798, 0.358132, 0.380497, 0.383051],
        'P_obs':[0,0.117684, 0.175074, 0.236679, 0.234442, 0.270303, 0.272637,
                 0.274075, 0.278981, 0.297151, 0.297797, 0.298722, 0.326645,
                 0.303198, 0.277822, 0.284194, 0.301471]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.set_index('times',inplace = True)

m = GEKKO(remote=False)

time_obs = df.index

t = m.time = time_obs

# ignore first measurement
tobj = np.ones(len(t))
tobj[0] = 0
mobj = m.Param(tobj)

Am= m.Param(df['A_obs'].values)
Cm= m.Param(df['C_obs'].values)
Pm= m.Param(df['P_obs'].values)

A,B,C,P = m.Array(m.Var,4,lb=0,fixed_initial=False)

k = m.Array(m.FV,6,value=1,lb=0)  
for ki in k:
    ki.STATUS = 1
k1,k2,k3,k4,k5,k6 = k

r = m.Array(m.Var,6,lb=0,value=0.0)
r1,r2,r3,r4,r5,r6 = r
   
m.Equation(r1 == k1 * A )
m.Equation(r2 == k2 * A * B )
m.Equation(r3 == k3 * C * B )
m.Equation(r4 == k4 * A )
m.Equation(r5 == k5 * A )
m.Equation(r6 == k6 * A * B )

#mass balance diff eqs, function calls rxn function 
m.Equation(A.dt() == - r1 - r2 - r4 - r5 - r6 )
m.Equation(B.dt() ==  r1 - r2 - r3 - r6 )
m.Equation(C.dt() ==  r2 - r3 + r4)
m.Equation(P.dt() ==  r3 + r5 + r6)

m.Minimize(mobj*(A-Am)**2)
m.Minimize(mobj*(C-Cm)**2)
m.Minimize(mobj*(P-Pm)**2)

m.options.IMODE = 5
m.options.SOLVER = 3 #IPOPT optimizer
m.options.RTOL = 1E-6
m.options.OTOL = 1E-6
m.options.NODES = 3
m.options.DIAGLEVEL = 0
#m.open_folder()
m.solve()

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(m.time,Am.value,'ro')
plt.plot(m.time,A.value,'r-',label='A')
plt.plot(m.time,Cm.value,'bo')
plt.plot(m.time,C.value,'b-',label='C')
plt.plot(m.time,Pm.value,'go')
plt.plot(m.time,P.value,'g-',label='P')
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Hi John, thanks for your comment. The mobj mask approach looks elegant to me and certainly useful in applications where you might have missing data at certain time points (for example multiple experimental batches).

More generally, when should we start considering using array variables? If any derivatives will once again face the issue you mention with orthogonal collocation? Are they mostly amenable to situations with no ODE's present?
Thanks for your time and feedbac!

Comment: The automatic time discretization in Gekko can be used with Arrays but only to define an array of differential variables. There is no easy way to access the individual elements of the automatic discretization without special functions such as those that let you fix or free a degree of freedom.